# Stock option impact when a company splits into two companies

Tags: employee-stock-options

What happens to an unvested stock option held in a company, that then splits into two new companies - are the options replicated?

Comment: You need to ask the company.  There are multiple possibilities and no one here can answer for your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

what happens during the transition from one company to two companies, will be discussed in the plan for the split. Those plans will discuss the timing and what will happen to the shares owned by the general public.

In addition there will be documents that discuss what will happen to the shares and options owned by the employees. The impact on the 401(k), pension, and the ESOP plans will also be covered. I know when I was involved in a split, the shares in the other company were frozen for a while, you couldn't be more shares, the some months later those shares in the 401(k) were sold and shares in the correct company were purchased.  I know options were addressed but I didn't own any at that time.